# How to query the character under the current cursor position or anywhere on the screen in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh, ansi-escape

I know that the following statement is a way to query the current cursor position:

```
echo -en '\033[6n'
```

Does anyone know how to query the character under the cursor or populate a array with the contents of the current screen/window?  I've searched through the ANSI terminal commands however a lot of these are pretty abstract and it doesn't look like they would do this properly.  I also looked into doing it with the `tcup` command with no luck.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ANSI terminal is not really required to be able to tell you what is on the screen. You're supposed to remember that yourself, if you need the information. The popular `ncurses` library does that, for example, although it only allows you to export the screen to a file, and the fileformat is not documented. In any event, `bash` doesn't use `ncurses`, so it really doesn't know anything about the state of the console.

Most probably, the screen you are talking about is actually an artifact of some terminal emulation program like `xterm`. Those programs run in userspace, and rarely (if ever) have an external query interface. However, linux does have a console (actually, a number of emulated consoles, but using the display's console mode) and it maintains the display memory for those consoles. And furthermore, it provides an interface for reading the console memory, usually available as `/dev/vcsN` (for values of `N` between 0 and the number of virtual consoles linux was compiled with). `/dev/vcs0` is the "current" console (the one which is visible).

Most linux distributions restrict access to `/dev/vcsN`, so if you want to play around with them you'll either need special privileges or you'll need to use root privileges to change the access permissions on the device files. (Ubuntu appears to provide `rw` access to users in group `tty`; check `ls -l /dev/vcs0` to see how your system does it.) (And, of course, you'll need to find the console :-) Try <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>; <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> will probably give you back your GUI.)

Once you've worked out the access issues, you could do something like `cp /dev/vcs0 console_memory` to take a look at it. What you'll find is that it is just a 2D array of characters with no newlines, and no indication of what the dimensions are. (You can get the dimensions with an `ioctl` or by looking at the environment variables `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS`.)

You could use `/dev/vcsa0` instead; it has a slightly different format using two bytes per character in order to store display attributes (foreground and background colours, mostly) as well as the character. Also, the first four bytes of `/dev/vcsaN` are the screen dimensions and cursor position (one byte per coordinate), which will save you the work of querying the cursor position.

Note that the console does not support a full Unicode character set. In fact, it can only display 512 different glyphs at once. In order to maximize the available glyph space, Linux may reassign some codes to needed symbols, and this mapping is not part of the console memory. So the code extracted from console memory might not have an obvious mapping to a Unicode code, but it should work fine for standard ANSI characters.

Comment: Thank you for assisting. I have been trying to avoid ncurses by all means and if I have to keep track of the screen then I'll have the script populate the array anytime there's a write to the screen I was just worried about this causing additional overhead. I'll give this a try now. I am working with psuedo terminals such as /dev/pts/1 on Centos so hopefully this will work with that as well. I was really hoping there was a escape sequence that could be sent to the terminal program which would return the contents of the text at the cursor position similar to the escape sequence in my question.